# How to center images of unknown dimensions in floating boxes of fixed dimensions?

Tags: html, css, css-float, css-position

In each row I have three boxes (blue) of fixed dimensions `(width: 299px, height: 307px)`
In every box there is an image (pink) of unknown dimensions. I know only `max-width: 262px` and `max-height: 200px`. Under the image there is some short two-three line text. I need to center images in the space above the text both horizontally and vertically.

I set the boxes to `float:left` and I set images `position:absolute`. I don't know how to make it work now :(

[image: Images need to be centered]

Comment: Maybe try adding  margin-left: 50%; and margin-right:50% to center the image

Comment: you may have used figure tag and line-height to center image vertically, test this http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mvwEy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to use table display, but that requires a lot of container elements in your markup. If the text height is fixed too, I would go with the "100% height ghost" technique described [here](http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/).

Applied in your case:

```
.box{      
  text-align: center;      
  position: relative;

  /* removes spaces between inline-block elements */
  /* another way is to add some negative margin on them */
  font-size: 0;

  /* account for text height */
  padding-bottom: 70px;

  /* +box width, height, float props etc. */
}

.box p{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 5%;
  width: 90%;    
  font-size: 14px;
}

/* the ghost, which forces vertical-align */
.box::before {
  content: '';
  height: 100%;     
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.box img {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;

  /* here you have to resize your images to fit within the box */
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%; 
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}
```

Markup:

```
<div class="box"> 
  <img ... />    
  <p>  text... </p>
</div>
```

test: http://cssdesk.com/MmrVV

Answer (score 1):

```
.image-class {
      display: inline-block;
}

.image-container-div {
      text-align: center;
}
```

It's ok to float the container.. but may not be ok to float the image class.

You could also have the image and text in separate container divs, so to avoid the text shifting positions.